# Map AppDomain into a friendly name using C#

Tags: c#, iis, nlog

So I have an IIS10 webserver, running a quite a few applications, like:

```
 + Default Web Site
     -First Application
     -Second Application
     -Third Application
```

We are using nLog to log stuff to a database, one of which is the current appdomain

`${appdomain:format=Format}`

as documented at https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/AppDomain-Layout-Renderer.

This is great, except when I look at our consolidated logs,  I see that the appdomain is logged as:

0002:/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036049222959352

I want to translate that into "Third Application" (So when I create a report, it will show up as "Third Application" instead of 0002:/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036049222959352.)

Conditions are:

- I can't change the layoutrenderer.
- I can't change the code of the applications.
- I have to do this AFTER the data is logged.  I assume that /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT is what I need to transform, and I can't do it in the app, only in reporting.

I've tried Microsoft.Web.Administration, something like:

```
using (ServerManager sm = new ServerManager()){
                var thisVal = (from s in sm.Sites
                               from app in s.Applications
                               from vDir in app.VirtualDirectories
                               where vDir.Path.Equals(currVal,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
                               select new KeyValuePair<string, string>(currVal, vDir.Path));
}
```

But I can't find the app root in there anywhere.  I believe it's the same thing as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms524308(v=vs.90), but that's the IIS metabase, which is apparently old and busted.

(the code above will be running on the same machine as the applications, so I don't have to worry about finding the correct server, just translating the name)

Comment: Know nothing about your setup. But if you have 3 applications. Then you probably have 3 web.config. Why not just change the web.config of the 3 application to include their individual "real" name?

Comment: I wish it were that easy -- but I can't do anything with the applications, the data in the database is all I can touch.

Comment: Are you sure that `0002:/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT-1-132036049222959352` belongs to `Third Application`? It must be something `0002:/LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/Third Application-1-132036049222959352` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate (and thus filter for) the AppDomain's id as such:

```
        using (ServerManager s = new ServerManager())
        {
            var processList = from m in Process.GetProcessesByName("w3wp") select m.Id;

            IEnumerable<WorkerProcess> workerP = (from p in s.ApplicationPools
                                                  from w in p.WorkerProcesses
                                                  where processList.Any(vn => vn == w.ProcessId)
                                                  select w);


            foreach (var workProcess in workerP)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(
                    $"{workProcess.AppPoolName} Id:{workProcess.ProcessId} AppDomains Count: {workProcess.ApplicationDomains?.Count}");
                var ad = workProcess.ApplicationDomains;
                if (!ad.Any()) continue;
                foreach (var curDomain in ad)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"AppDomain: {curDomain.Id} {curDomain.VirtualPath}");
                }
            }
        }
```

This will give you output that shows the AppDomain's ids, that you can get the vdir from:

```
DefaultAppPool Id:33180 AppDomains Count: 1
AppDomain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/
```